# App crashes when clicking on UISearchbar (searchDisplayController)

Tags: iphone, ios, crash, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am implementing the searchdisplay controller on the iPhone App, but will hit the following error when I try to click on the search bar (after a few tries)

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x30000008)
```

[image]

Snippet of my code as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

  //Setting up the search bar for search display controller
  UISearchBar *tempBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 34, 320, 44)];
  self.sBar = tempBar;
  [tempBar release];
  self.sBar.delegate = self;
  self.sBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#b6c0c7"];
  self.sBar.placeholder = @"Search DM friends";

  self.searchDisplayController = [[[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:sBar contentsController:self]autorelease];
  [self setSearchDisplayController:searchDisplayController];
  [searchDisplayController setDelegate:self];
  [searchDisplayController setSearchResultsDataSource:self];
  self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.delegate = self;
}


- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *headerView = [[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 78)]autorelease];
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#ebe7e6"];

    if (tableView != self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView){
        //Search

        UILabel *tagFriendsTitle = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 320, 16)];
        tagFriendsTitle.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
        tagFriendsTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        tagFriendsTitle.text = @"Who should see this? Tag them!";

        [headerView addSubview:tagFriendsTitle];

        //THIS IS WHERE I GET MY EXC_BAD_ACCESS error
        [headerView addSubview:self.sBar];

        [tagFriendsTitle release];

    }
    return headerView;

}
```

I am not sure which part of my code is causing the error, but it seems that the sBar deallocated from memory when I try to add it to header subview? But I am not sure why I needed to click on the search bar multiple times before that happens.

This is how it looks on the iPhone, the searchbar forms part of the headerview

[image]

Comment: self.sBar is it a retain or assign property ?

Comment: I am using retain @property (nonatomic, retain) UISearchBar *sBar

Answer (score 3):

go to product>edit schems> enable nszombie objects and see what's the prblem there

Answer (score 1):

If this is an assign property, you should probably change it to a retain property. And don't forget to set the property to nil in `dealloc` and `viewDidUnload`.